# Why join is better than subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite, t-sql

I have read a many of articles that show that join is better than SubQuery.But they did not explain why!

Can you explain to me why join  is better than SubQuery?

Answer (score 2):

This is not always the case.

In SQL Server the use of `EXISTS/NOT EXISTS` can often out perform the equivalent query written using the `JOIN` keyword. SQL server has efficient semi join and anti semi join operators.

The problem with correlated sub queries is when they force a nested loops algorithm with the sub query repeatedly evaluated individually for each outer row.

Comment: The thing with exists/not exists is that it still a seperate query, the optimizer with likely still perform a join underwater depending on the query. Ofcourse exist is optimal in many other situations.

Comment: @NLwino `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` subqueries are (anti)semi-joins, not proper joins and they often lead to different plans - mainly because the results can be different. And they are certainly not separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

Join is executed once in the query to obtain the super set of the data and then applies the filters if any.

Subquery is executed multiple times for each matching records.

Answer (score 0):

A thing people ofthen forget is that the optimizer knows it better then most programmers. 
I recommend to read this article. [SQL server engine knows the best](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/06/06/sql-server-subquery-or-join-various-options-sql-server-engine-knows-the-best/)

subquery/join/exists/in are likely executed the same way by the optimizer.